# How to back up a password database and to keep 15 older versions?

Tags: bash, backup, android, keepass, unison

I mainly work on linux at home and on windows at work. I  use the open source password manager `KeePass` and it works great. I back up my document files often using Unison file synchroniser. I use Keepass on windows, linux and android.

I would like some more *redundancy* specifically with KeePass as sometimes the database would become corrupt. I noticed that only when opening a file on my Android device. It was a good thing I had a couple of older copies around, so the loss was not too great. However I would like to make the password database backup process safer and automatic.

Ideally I would like to do backup when there is a saved change in the database and to keep about 10 or 15 older versions around. Additionally those versions would be replicated between two directories (one on USB stick) via Unison and independently from Unison - to Dropbx (hence appearing also on Android).

What would be the smartest solution to automate this process, or perhaps there are some better solutions ready in the open source domain?

I thought of writing a shell script that would check if the file has changed; if it has then make a new copy of it and keep 15 previous versions in the same directory.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a shell script that would check if the file has changed; if it has then make a new copy of it and keep 15 previous versions in the same directory.

Comment: I sync my keepas data over Windows, Linux and Android using only Dropbox, and its history feature has already saved my life after a file corruption.

Comment: When using Linux you could put the database in its own tiny filesystem and do filesystem snapshots (BtrFS and snapper for example).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a feature called Versioning, which is available in [multiple online back up services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_online_backup_services#Versioning).

Since you already using it, you should be happy to know that [by default](https://www.dropbox.com/help/122/en), Dropbox saves a history of all deleted and earlier versions of files for 30 days for all Dropbox accounts.

Assuming you are syncing your KeePass database to Dropbox weekly, that would give you up to 4 previous versions to fall back up.

Comment: I sync my keepas data over Windows, Linux and Android using only Dropbox, and its history feature has already saved my life after a file corruption.

Comment: Yes, I still keep using it, but sometimes it creates (conflicted.copy) which is a bit annoying.